# Why does the REGEXP_LIKE function treat the letter 'e' as upper case instead of lower case?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In my pl/sql script Oracle treats the letter 'e' as upper case when searching by the [:upper:] Character Class Syntax.

i.e.

```
REGEXP_LIKE('e', '[:upper:]')

REGEXP_LIKE('e', '[:lower:]')
```

Related Oracle docs can be found here:

[Oracle - Multilingual Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819)

[Oracle - REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)

Comment: If I add a '\e' as follows: '[:upper:]\e', I can work around it.

Comment: Regarding the type, I've used both CHAR and VARCHAR2(1), and get the same result.  Regarding the value, in this case it is the letter 'e'.

Comment: After some testing, it looks like all other upper, lower, and numeric characters work as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character classes seem to work when you surround them with brackets `[]` as in :

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual WHERE regexp_like('e', '[[:upper:]]');

DUMMY
-----

SQL> SELECT * FROM dual WHERE regexp_like('E', '[[:upper:]]');

DUMMY
-----
X
```

When you use single brackets Oracle treats them as a list of characters, i-e the following works because `u` is contained in the string `:upper:`:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual WHERE regexp_like('u', '[:upper:]');

DUMMY
-----
X
```

Comment: +1 Or in other words: `[:upper:]` is exactly equivalent to: `[epru:]`

Comment: Awesome, thanks Vincent.  It works like a charm.  Strange it even works at all for other letters.  And just to clarify, I was using it in a pl/sql statement and not a sql expression.  I confirmed that it works the same in a pl/sql conditional statement.

Comment: ridgerunner, I haven't been able to find [epru:] in Oracle's documentation.  Do you have a reference link?

Comment: @Glenn Wark - Simple. The `[...]` is just a normal character class which is common to most (if not all) regex engines. See: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 4):

As and additional note to Vincent's answer this is a common regex pitfall. See e.g. [Why is using a POSIX character class in my regex pattern giving unexpected results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2333069/) - there you can just read Perl as Oracle SQL as *the regex problem and solution are the same than in your case*.

Here is also the same case illustrated with GNU grep:

```
$ echo E | grep -e '[:upper:]'
grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]
$ echo E | grep -e '[[:upper:]]'
E
$
```

So nothing Oracle special here.